# Rails custom message system, conversation is not created properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, messaging

So I created a custom message system based on https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-messaging-system-with-rails-and-actioncable/

It worked great until I encountered a bug where it could not create new conversations properly. (Conversation is named insconversation in my code)

```
class PersonalMessagesController
...
  def create
    @insconversation ||= Insconversation.create(author_id: current_user.id, //This part seems to be having issues
                                      receiver_id: @receiver.id)
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build(personal_message_params)
    @personal_message.insconversation_id = @insconversation.id
    @personal_message.save!

    flash[:success] = "Your message was sent!"
   redirect_to insconversation_path(@insconversation)
  end
...
```

The message itself is saved into the Mysql database, but it's parent "insconversation_id" is left null, similarly on the "insconversation" table no new conversation is added. I used render :text => and insconversation and it's id are both null, (as in failed to be created).

The errror message I recived is at the redirect_to part 
    No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"insconversations", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

And the personal message view

```
view/Personal_Message
<h1>New message to <%= @receiver.name %></h1>   //receiver is properly identified

<%= form_for @personal_message do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'receiver_id', @receiver.id %>

  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x3", required:true %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

conversation controller

```
class InsconversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_insconversation, except: [:index]
  before_action :check_participating!, except: [:index]

  def index
    @insconversations = Insconversation.participating(current_user).order('updated_at DESC')
  end

  def show
    @insconversation = Insconversation.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @personal_message = PersonalMessage.new
  end

  private

  def set_insconversation
    @insconversation = Insconversation.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def check_participating!
    redirect_to root_path unless @insconversation && @insconversation.participates?(current_user)
  end
end
```

Edit:

I just checked the SQL log

```
 Insconversation Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `insconversations` WHERE `insconversations`.`author_id` = 2 AND `insconversations`.`receiver_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `personal_messages` (`body`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('8', 2, '2017-04-24 00:31:11', '2017-04-24 00:31:11')
```

The system seems to think the Inconversation already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID on a model is set automatically by Rails so the part of your code that you comment that you're having issues with is not the actual problem. The issue is with the line:

```
   redirect_to insconversation_path(@insconversation)
```

The message states that you're missing the params for insconversation ID. You just need to make a slight adjustment to this line to get the ID.

```
redirect_to insconversation_path(@insconversation.id)
```

Or you can just do

```
redirect_to @insconversation
```

and Rails will infer the rest.

Comment: neither works, the second one redirects to the list of conversations, but it does not solves the issue of the new conversation row never being created in the SQL table. I am using phpmyadmin to check over the tables

Comment: @Jay Okay. Well let's start with the error that it is throwing which is a routing and params error. Also where the second solution I proposed is routing you to the index, I'm a bit curious. Run `rails routes` and list out the routes related to `insconversation`.

Comment: insconversations_path GET /insconversations(.:format) 
insconversations#index

insconversation_path GET /insconversations/:id(.:format) 
insconversations#show

Comment: @Jay Okay that gives me some confidence that the routes are there. So the routes are there, but the ID that is being sent is nil. The ID that should be sent is coming from the `@insconversation`. So `@insconversation` instance has no ID. But in Rails an ID will always be automatically created upon Save or Create. So I believe that it's not actually running Create because the instance variable `insconversation` is already assigned. Is there any reason you're using `||=` in your create method? Normally you'd just use `=`

Comment: I changed it to = no difference occured. SQL-  Insconversation Exists (3.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `insconversations` WHERE `insconversations`.`author_id` = 3 AND `insconversations`.`receiver_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
 is still displayed as the query, the system thinks it already exists, which causes it to SELECT from the table instead of adding to it

Comment: @Jay I am racking my brain. Calling Insconversation.create shouldn't care if it exists.  Is it possible that there is a `has_one` relationship between the user and `Insconversation` model? (i.e. You can only have one `Insconversation`) so it's not letting you create it? The other possibility is that Insconversations has a validation that isn't satisfied?

Comment: User model: has_many :authored_insconversations, class_name: 'Insconversation', foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :received_insconversations, class_name: 'Insconversation', foreign_key: 'received_id'

Comment: The system is suppose to check if the conversation exists, if it does then it modifes the existing conversation row. Otherwise it creates a new one

Comment: @Jay okay...then the SQL logs are fine and the ||= is okay as well. You pointed to the SQL logs as if they were the problem that it wasn't creating the Insconversation. But it seems as though it is expected behaviour. It's just that whatever `@Insconversation` instance it is referring to in that view, is not correct. Here's the source code. Perhaps you can find discrepency between your PersonalMessagesControlle and theirs: https://github.com/bodrovis/Sitepoint-source/blob/master/Custom_Messaging_System/app/controllers/personal_messages_controller.rb

Comment: What do you mean expected behavior, the create method is reached, and it says inconversation.create doesn't a create method mean it must add to the database?

Comment: how about adding directly to the conversation controller?

Comment: add_index :insconversations, [:author_id, :receiver_id], unique: true
I found that in the database migration, how does unique work if it is two indices?

Comment: @Jay it is saying the combination of values of those two columns must be unique as it's written. In this instance I imagine it's so you only have 1 message thread between a pair of two people. That is part of why it's not creating a new insconversation. It already exists for the pair of people you're creating it for. I wonder if it's possible if in your Dev db you created this insconversation earlier while testing but without the rest of the code. And now it's not acting as you expect cause it already exists. You could do rails db:drop and then create and migrate (will wipe out all data)

Comment: Don't do this on prod btw. This is just for your dev/testing environment.

Comment: the issue is that im testing with users that have no conversation yet, it needs to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Do you still need this fixed? I was having same problem.  Use this:

```
class PersonalMessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_conversation!

  def new
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation) and return if @conversation
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build
  end

  def create
    @conversation ||= Conversation.create(author_id: current_user.id,
                                      receiver_id: @receiver.id)
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build(personal_message_params)
    @personal_message.conversation_id = @conversation.id
    @personal_message.save!

    flash[:success] = "Your message was sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation)
  end

  private

  def personal_message_params
    params.require(:personal_message).permit(:body)
  end

  def find_conversation!
    if params[:receiver_id]
      @receiver = User.find_by(id: params[:receiver_id])
      redirect_to(root_path) and return unless @receiver
      @conversation = Conversation.between(current_user.id, @receiver.id)[0]
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.find_by(id: params[:conversation_id])
      redirect_to(root_path) and return unless @conversation && @conversation.participates?(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```